# How do I print a success message after a successful fetch?

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

I am trying to use fetch and post methods to change a value. This all works fine. My problem is moving on after the fetch (in this example, I want to post a simple "ok"). The problem is that it never actually gives me that message. It gives me the "error" message, when I change to a wrong API.

```
async function sendCon(number) {
  let data = JSON.stringify(number);
  console.log("I accept")
  await fetch(acceptAPI, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
  }).then(function() {
    console.log("ok");
  }).catch(function() {
    console.log("error");
  })
}
```

Please help, I've been trying to figure this out for three days.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try your api in POST man or in any REST client? seems like API is always responding Error.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the response to a variable and check if the response has a status code of `200`.

```
async function sendCon(number) {
  try {
    let data = JSON.stringify(number);
    const response = await fetch(acceptAPI, {
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
    });

    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log("ok");
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```